# how to export all files in a directory so that i can use them with dot operator?

Tags: reactjs, import, module, export, gif

I have a directory with so many gif files. for using these files in `react` I have to import them separately and use them in `img` tag:

```
import Cube from '../gifs/Cube.gif'
<img src={Cube} />
```

if gif files weren't so large I may create an `index.js` file and import all files and export them:

```
import BeanEater from './BeanEater.gif'
import Cube from './Cube.gif'
import Eclipse from './Eclipse.gif'
import Gear from './Gear.gif'
import Infinity from './Infinity. gif'
import Reload from './Reload.gif'
import Spinner from './Spinner.gif'

export default{
    BeanEater,
    Cube,
    Eclipse,
    Gear,
    Infinity,
    Reload,
    Spinner
}
```

I have an index.js in the src/gifs folder that exports all gif files in the src/gifs folder.
I want to import all gif files in the index.js file. if I do it this way:

```
import * as gifs from '.'
```

and export them this way:

```
export default gifs
```

I can't access gif files separately in other components:

```
import gifs from './gifs'
<img src={gifs.Cube} /> // doesn't show anything
```

how to handle this situation? (how to import gif files in index.js and how to export them so that I can access files separately in other components with the dot operator)

Comment: Let me know if the answer worked for you or not which i have added

Comment: my problem has two parts: 1-how to import all gif files? 2-how to export imported files so that I can access them from other components with the dot operator. you answered the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
export default{
    BeanEater,
    Cube,
    Eclipse,
    Gear,
    Infinity,
    Reload,
    Spinner
}
```

to

```
export{
    BeanEater,
    Cube,
    Eclipse,
    Gear,
    Infinity,
    Reload,
    Spinner
}
```

and use the same import

```
import * as gifs from '../gifs'
```

Comment: my problem has two parts: 1-how to import all gif files? 2-how to export imported files so that I can access them from other components with the dot operator. you answered the second question

Comment: export without default when you need to export mutliple gifs, also i am little confused where are you putting the gif in the public or outside, are you using cra or custom

Comment: gif files are in src/gifs folder.

Comment: Honestly, I am very confused about how to explain it to you.

Comment: So the second pblm is solved isn't so now instead of importing one by one gif you need to import all the gif in a single import command isn't

Comment: I didn't understood the first part, that why shouldn't be it in separate files, which will give more code clarity isn't

Comment: okay cool let me know, will try within my knowledge

Comment: I can not explain more clearly than this. So if I still explain badly, leave me like that. Maybe the traditional way works better. It takes time though.

Comment: I am quiet confused, when you have different types of gifs you have it will be easy to separate it, because it will be more easy, Also let me know if there is a way of using all the gif in same file, didn't find anything will update if if i found something

Comment: thank you so much. I can't explain it more.  I can solve my problem by importing files separately and exporting them as you say. I just wanted to know is there a better way and apparently, there is not. thank you again